# force execution of code block org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I frequently have to rerun code blocks in my org-mode reports because some corrections were needed upstream.

Is there a way to force the execution of a block?

Now I have to remove the results from the block in order to rerun it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C-c C-v C-e` will force the execution of a code block, if there is no `:eval no` linked to it.

I've written `org-babel-force-execute-src-block` to even go around that, without having to manually delete the `:eval no` directive. And I've bound it to `H-f` ("f" for "force") in my config. See https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven/blob/master/emacs-leuven.el for détails (or the Org file, which contains comments and from which the `.el` is tangled).